# Why is still countdown necessary?

Tags: launch, rockets

Although I do enjoy counting down the last ten seconds before rocket launch, I am still puzzled: Why do we still use countdown? What is real purpose behind the countdowm?

Why do we need to launch rocket exactly at (example) 10:15:00 ?

Is it just a thing we are used to do, because "thats how we do it from beginning" or is there any practical purpose of countdowns to exact time of launch?

Comment: It would be nice if people flagging a question as a duplicate give a reference to the duplicates for us wandering folks who just stumbled upon an interesting question...